# Day light Saving not working in salesforce org

Tags: apex, timezone

We have used below code to covert time in different timezones, but unfortunately even if [Salesforce claims to handle daylight saving adjustment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm), it's not considering day light saving offsets

Expected Offset : -25200000

Actual offset : -28800000

Can someone give me some hint?

```
Timezone tzUsr = TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(2016, 12, 22, 9, 0, 0);

Integer OffsetpresentDate = tzUsr.getOffset(myDate); 

Integer minuteDiff = OffsetpresentDate/60000;
Datetime convertedDateTime = myDate.addminutes(minuteDiff);
```

o/p which I get :-

**myDate**:2016-12-22 03:30:00

**OffsetpresentDate**:-28800000

**convertedDateTime**:2016-12-21 19:30:00

**Expected** : convertedDateTime:2016-12-21 20:30:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the offset calculation works. Have a look at the documentation for the `TimeZone` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm) (emphasis mine):

> **getOffset(date)**
>   Returns the time zone offset, in milliseconds, *of the specified date* to the GMT time zone.
>   ...
>   **Usage**
>   The returned offset is adjusted for daylight saving time *if the date argument falls within daylight saving time for this time zone*.

So if you specify a combination of `TimeZone` and `Datetime` that falls within Daylight Savings Time, this method calculates the daylight savings offset. Otherwise, it calculates the standard offset.

---

In light of the above, you are incorrect about your expected offset. On December 21st of 2016, Los Angeles was on [**Pacific *Standard* Time**, for which the UTC offset is -8](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst).

If you look at the conversion, -8 hours = -480 minutes = -28800000 milliseconds. The correct offset is to subtract 8 hours, which is what you're seeing. **Salesforce behavior is correct, it's your expected value that needs adjustment.**

---

There are plenty of tables out there which you can use to determine when Daylight Savings Time starts and ends. I found one [here](http://www.timetemperature.com/tzus/daylight_saving_time.shtml):

```
Year    DST Begins at 2 a.m.    DST Ends at 2 a.m.
2009    March 08                November 1
2010    March 14                November 7
2011    March 13                November 6
2012    March 11                November 4
2013    March 10                November 3
2014    March 09                November 2
2015    March 08                November 1
2016    March 13                November 6
2017    March 12                November 5
2018    March 11                November 4
2019    March 10                November 3
2020    March 8                 November 1
2021    March 14                November 7
```

As you can see from the above table, **any date between `2016-11-06` and `2017-03-12` in `America/Los_Angeles` observes Standard Time, *not* Daylight Savings Time**.

---

The above dates line up exactly with the offset calculated by Salesforce. You can see for yourself by executing this script in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
static Integer getPacificOffset(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day)
{
    return TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')
        .getOffset(Datetime.newInstanceGmt(year, month, day)) /
        (1000 * 60 * 60);
}

system.debug(2014);
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2014, 3, 9)); // -8
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2014, 3, 10)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2014, 11, 2)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2014, 11, 3)); // -8

system.debug(2015);
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2015, 3, 8)); // -8
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2015, 3, 9)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2015, 11, 1)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2015, 11, 2)); // -8

system.debug(2016);
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2016, 3, 13)); // -8
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2016, 3, 14)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2016, 11, 6)); // -7
system.debug(getPacificOffset(2016, 11, 7)); // -8
```

Comment: Could you please help in handling such situation in apex class? We are actually considering that Salesforce will handle to calculate right Offset like in PST : UTC - 8 and in PDT UTC -7

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adrian's excellent answer, perhaps this can help

My UTIL class used to take a local timezone + date + time and convert to a GMT value

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
//  getDateTimeGmt  : Returns a datetime in GMT from a timezoneId, date and time object
//   Example: getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',someDate,someTime)
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
public static Datetime getDateTimeGmt(String tzId, Date d, Time t) {
    DateTime    res;
    if (tzId == null || d == null || t == null) return res;
    Timezone    tz          = Timezone.getTimeZone(tzId);
    DateTime    dt          = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(d,t);
    Integer     offsetMs    = tz.getOffset(dt);                 // #ms offset from datetime in Tz to GMT
    Integer     offsetMins  = offsetMs / (1000 * 60);
    res = dt.addMinutes(-1 * offsetMins);

    return res;
}

//  testGetDateTimeGmt
@isTest
private static void testGetDateTimeGmt() {
    String  tz;
    Date    d;
    Time    t;

    //  Verify Pacific Std (January) and DST (May)
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2020,1,1,19,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2020,1,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -8 hours - not DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2020,5,1,18,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2020,5,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -7 hours -  DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2020,5,2,4,0,0),    Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2020,5,1),Time.newInstance(21,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -7 hours -  DST but GMT is next day');

    // Go the other way - Europe/Paris
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2020,1,1,10,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('Europe/Paris',Date.newInstance(2020,1,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by +1 hours - not DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2020,6,1,9,0,0),    Util.getDateTimeGmt('Europe/Paris',Date.newInstance(2020,6,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by +2 hours - DST');
}
```